# how to increment a variable in first activity depending on the TextView values in second activity

Tags: android

hi all I have a variable in first activity i need to add values returned from second activity and store it in this variables. Switching between activities happens multiple times.... Any ideas..?
here is a piece of code which stores current value each time and not the Sum of it...

```
double quantity = Double.parseDouble(s1[1]);
double amount = Double.parseDouble(s1[2]);

if(s1[3].equals(""))
{
    totalint = (quantity*(amount));
    Log.d("hitherebbbbbbb",((Double)totalint).toString());
    grandTotal =+totalint; 
}
else
{
    deduction = Double.parseDouble(s1[3]);
    totalint = ((quantity*(amount-deduction*amount/100)));
    Log.d("hitherebbbbbbb",((Double)totalint).toString());
    grandTotal =+totalint; 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the amount of variables stays the same you could always use sharedpreferences. They are super simple to use and you can add a sharedpreference listener to update your activity when a value is changed. If the amount of variables changes (eg you have 3 integers at one time but maybe your user can change it so you need 5) then I would do something a little more complex that may not be the best option but I like it because I find it more simple than a database. Let me know which scenario best describes your situation and I'll get you more documentation.

Comment: Thnx GQGK.. i thought of same.. but looking to do it within code without using resources...

Comment: @nagesh - Doing it in code only is dangerous. If the user presses Home and then comes back to your application, there's a chance that the system would have killed off the process in between. In that case, any data kept in shared variables will be lost. The best way to avoid the problem is to stick with the recommended approaches (startActivityForResult/onActivityResult) or relying on one of the persistent data methods like shared preferences.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting Ted... I'm new to android.. let me follow them

Comment: Just let me know if you need help with it. It's pretty simple to implement and I have some sample code if you learn best from that.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to return the values from the second activity through its return intent and do a startActivityForResult() in the first activity.

you would do this by creating an intent in your second activity, setting any relevant return data, and calling

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
finish();
```

You will be called back in the onActivityResult() method when the second activity is finished. You would then extract the values from the return intent and update your local storage.

Comment: i have done evrything possible.. its fetching values from it... but its not adding them...

Comment: only thing i'm left wid to do is store those values in shared preference and then add.. i did't do it assuming it makes the process complex..

Comment: You could store the values in some storage on the Application object. This has a longer lifecycle than your Activity (stays around for as long as any activity from the application is alive). If you need longer persistence, you need to look at filesystem/preferences/db.